# How to clear IE cache without deleting files in use?

Tags: c#, browser

I am uploading image files in my mvc web app. I want to show this as logo on my site whenever I upload any selected image. For this, i need to clear the browser cache. Following is set of functions I am using for clearing cache.

```
void clearIECache()
    {
      ClearFolder(new DirectoryInfo(Environment.GetFolderPath
         (Environment.SpecialFolder.InternetCache)));
    }

    void ClearFolder(DirectoryInfo folder)
    {
      foreach (FileInfo file in folder.GetFiles())
      { file.Delete(); }
      foreach (DirectoryInfo subfolder in folder.GetDirectories())
      { ClearFolder(subfolder); }
    }
```

Problem with above code is that it interrupts whenever it tries to delete any file that's in use. I want to skip such files sothat it can work smoothly. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Is this for your local app, or for a remote user?  How are you going to get the code to execute on your remote user's machine?

Answer (score 2):

Use [Try/Catch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw%28VS.80%29.aspx) to trap the errors and ignore them:

```
    foreach (FileInfo file in folder.GetFiles())
    {
        try
        {
            file.Delete();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
           // Swallow "File in use" errors.
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you do this, make sure you always include a comment in the empty catch block, explaining to the programmer that follows you why the empty catch block is there.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using in your scripts using jquery this line of code to correct the browsers do caching:

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
```

Comment: This question is about C#. There is no jQuery in C#