# Delete IE Explorer cache from Windows application

Tags: c#, windows

I need to delete all internet explorer cached files from my application, this is my code:

```
void clearIECache()
{
    ClearFolder(
        new DirectoryInfo(
            Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.InternetCache)));
}

void ClearFolder(DirectoryInfo folder)
{
    foreach (FileInfo file in folder.GetFiles())
    {
        try
        {
            file.Delete();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

It says that I have no authorization to delete files, I tried to delete files in that folder from console and it gives the same error...

Is there another way to clear explorer cache ?

Comment: Do you have the permision to delete the files?

Comment: Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3111102/how-to-clear-ie-cache-without-deleting-files-in-use

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deleting IE Cache and Cookies using C# Code in WPF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16167984/deleting-ie-cache-and-cookies-using-c-sharp-code-in-wpf)

Comment: See [this kb article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326201) for how to do this using PInvoke